# windows 2003 server scheduled task resources

Tags: windows-server-2003, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

It seems I've suddenly become sys admin for our windows 2003 server boxes, despite having no experience with this.

At the moment we're having issues with scheduled tasks and I have no idea where to really start with them.  They seem to be a magical bane that require a lot of trickery to get working.

What I am looking for is a good set of resources for Scheduled tasks, using them to back up log files to other servers and other system Admin type things.  I know this is a horribly vague question, but the problem i am having with them would possibly be even more vague.

Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduled tasks are simply programs that run at certain times (or in response to certain events).  They usually run as a user account that is NOT the current logged in user. Because of this they need a little care in testing since it is often the case that the user accounts will not share the same rights.

In general, you test them by logging as the user the task runs as and run the identical command to see what the results are as you'd expect.

Here is some information from Technet that will get you started http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779419(WS.10).aspx